Control Glade Device with AtTiny85
I am a programmer, without knowledge of electronics and I want to be able to make a control that allows:
intervene the power supply in a Glade aromatizing device, so that it is activated only during the day.
For example between 8am and 6pm.
These devices glade, when the batteries are inserted and the device has the selector set other than off. automatically discharges flavoring (at the beginning of the configured period of 9, 18 and 36 minutes).
So my idea is to be able to make a mini board that intervenes the connection of the batteries on its positive side and that with this is powered, for example, an attiny85 or similar, where a logic can be generated to implement a deep sleep of the device during the hours in that the use is not necessary (I know that this device does not have RTC, but that would be a secondary issue)
So with a pad that on one side receives energy from the AA batteries, has an insulating medium and on the other end has a conductive side through which the attiny can supply the 3v to the aroma device so that the automatic aroma discharge is triggered. and after that the power supply is cut off again until the next cycle controlled by the attiny.
main idea:
that the device generates aroma discharges only between 8am and 6pm
I attach a crude diagram of the idea that occurs to me to do it.
I apologize if my proposal at the component level is very wrong.
I hope you can help an enthusiast to learn basic electronics.
thank you so much



Unless you are wanting to do this yourself for the learning experience, I would get an AC powered device (or a battery eliminator) and plug it into a timer.

Indeed, I want to learn electronics with this idea and see how far it can go in an optimal way and with low-cost components.

What does “touch battery” mean? Without that knowledge, you may or may not be shorting out the battery.

that is a piece that has 2 sides that are conductors and the middle part is insulated. From the part that touches the battery, I take out the power for the attiny and then the part that says touch device, is where the aromatizing device is powered.

Could someone help me know if my approach is valid to be able to supply power to the device?
thank you so much
